# mysql: Intergrate values of a table alog time

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to integrate the v values with timediffs of t from one row to the next, in a table like this: "p_values"=

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| measure_id | v     | t        |
+------------+-------+----------+
|          1 |    32 | 10:45:00 |
|          2 |    17 | 10:42:00 |
|          3 |    20 | 10:39:00 |
|          4 |    21 | 10:36:00 |
|          5 |    35 | 10:33:00 |
|          6 |    59 | 10:30:00 |
|          7 |    47 | 10:27:00 |
|          8 |    45 | 10:24:00 |
|          9 |    40 | 10:21:00 |
|         10 |    39 | 10:18:00 |
|         11 |    42 | 10:15:00 |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

I want to integrate the v values with timediffs of t:

```
result = v[1]*(t[1]-t[2]) + v[2]*(t[2]-t[3]) + v[3]*(t[3]-t[4]) + ...
```

Can I do this on a single query?

I'm trying creating a table joining each column with the column below, like this:

```
select * from 
    (select  measure_id, v, t from p_values order by t desc) a, 
    (select  measure_id, v, t from p_values order by t desc) b 
where a.t < b.t group by b.t desc;

+------------+----+----------+------------+----+----------+
| measure_id | v  | t        | measure_id | v  | t        |
+------------+----+----------+------------+----+----------+
|          9 | 83 | 11:12:00 |         10 | 25 | 11:15:00 |
|          8 | 90 | 11:09:00 |          9 | 83 | 11:12:00 |
|          7 | 24 | 11:06:00 |          8 | 90 | 11:09:00 |
|          6 | 29 | 11:03:00 |          7 | 24 | 11:06:00 |
|          5 | 72 | 11:00:00 |          6 | 29 | 11:03:00 |
|          4 | 28 | 10:57:00 |          5 | 72 | 11:00:00 |
|          3 | 22 | 10:54:00 |          4 | 28 | 10:57:00 |
|          2 | 42 | 10:51:00 |          3 | 22 | 10:54:00 |
|          1 | 35 | 10:48:00 |          2 | 42 | 10:51:00 |
|          0 | 31 | 10:45:00 |          1 | 35 | 10:48:00 |
+------------+----+----------+------------+----+----------+
```

Based on this table, I calculate the integral value in a single query as:

```
select sum(v) from 
    (select (a.v + b.v)/2 * (TIME_TO_SEC(b.t) - TIME_TO_SEC(a.t))/3600 as v from
        (select  measure_id, v, t from p_values order by t desc) a, 
        (select  measure_id, v, t from p_values order by t desc) b 
    where a.t < b.t group by b.t desc) as c;

+---------+
| sum(v)  |
+---------+
| 246.948 |
+---------+
```

But I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Important: measure_id is incremental, but with gaps. The table has many more measures from different devices, and I have to filter the ones I need. I didn't write the sql filtering part for simplicity, but this may be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(value)
from
    (select (p.v*(t-@prev)) as value,
           @prev:=t
    from (select @prev:=0) sess, p_values p
    order by p.measure_id desc) raw
```

Here we introduce a variable @prev where we store value from previous row (but we sort in desc order).

Then just sum the results

UPDATE query for the fiddle

```
select sum(value)
from
    (select (p.v*(t-@prev)) as value,
           @prev:=v
    from (select @prev:=0) sess, p_values p
    order by v desc) raw
```

Comment: +1 for the more general solution, if `measure_id` does have gaps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it to work. This query: `select pv_value as v, @prev:=pv_time, pv_time from (select @prev:=0) s, valueparameter_20140605 p where deviceid=10013 and paramid=1 and pv_time > "09:00:00" order by pv_time asc limit 5;` generates this table: ` | 31611 | 09:03:00       | 09:03:00 |`

Comment: You can create SQLfiddle and post in your question (as update)

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the `measure_id` is incremental with no gaps, then you can do this with a self join.  The resulting query is something like this:

```
select sum(p1.v*(p2.t - p1.t))
from p_values p1 join
     p_values p2
     on p2.measure_id = p1.measure_id + 1;
```

A couple of notes.  First, this ignores the last `v` value, because there is no matching row.  The question doesn't specify what to do in this case, so I assume you don't want that difference included.

I also left the simple notation for difference of times.  Your question appears to be about handling the values from different rows, not actually calculating the difference of the `time` column.  That, in turn, depends on the data type for the column, which is not specified in the question.

Finally, your subquery has a fatal flaw.  It has [columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  This uses a group by extension that the documentation explicitly warns against using.

Comment: +1 for the simpler solution if measure_id has no gaps

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: measure_id is incremental, but with gaps. The table has many more measures from different devices, and I have to filter the ones I need. I didn't write the sql filtering part for simplicity, but this may be important.

Comment: @piedramania . . . In that case, you should build on the solution from StanislavL.  It is closer to what you will ultimately need.  I'm leaving this here because it answers the question as originally written.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. Actually your answer is really helpful, especially on that of the subquery fatal flaw.